# Probable bug in weak_ptr passed to a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, g++

In this code example, we pass a `std::shared_ptr<int>` to a thread, and expect it is weakened to a `std::weak_ptr<int>`. But in Visual Studio 2019, `t` takes a strong reference and the output of this program is "pw alive", in both debug and release builds. Same problem on linux with compiler `g++ -lpthread`.

This toy example is motivated by the more serious case where thread `t` does some long computations, and then sends results through shared resources `t` receives as arguments. Those resources may be deleted by other threads during `t`'s computation, in which case `t` becomes useless and can be terminated early. But because of this (suspected) bug, `t` keeps the resources alive and wastes memory and calculation time.

Is this really a bug, or I am misunderstanding the relationship between `weak_ptr` and `shared_ptr` ? If this is a bug, do you know where to report it ? Probably at different places for Visual Studio and g++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void TestWeakPtrAlive(std::weak_ptr<int> pw)
{
  // wait for main thread to delete pw
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
  std::shared_ptr<int> p = pw.lock();
  std::cout << (p ? "pw alive" : "pw dead")
            << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<int> p = std::make_shared<int>(18);
  std::thread t(TestWeakPtrAlive, p);
  p = nullptr;
  t.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, your question is, "every implementation I've tried does the same thing, and I don't think that's what it should do, so aren't they all buggy?" <g>

Comment: Works as expected. Thread takes `p` by value, stores it, then thread function starts taking `weak_ptr` created based on stored `p` by value. You have two instances of `shared_ptr` one in `main` function , the second in thread, so `weak_ptr` must be alived (by `p = nullptr`, only one release is made, object is still alive with reference counter to 1).

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes. And where to report the bug if they are.

Comment: @rafix07 The thread is called with function `TestWeakPtrAlive`, that requests an `std::weak_ptr<int>` as argument. Why does it copy the `shared_ptr`, instead of constructing a `weak_ptr` from it ?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that `p = nullptr;` in `main` will be executed *before* `std::shared_ptr<int> p = pw.lock();` in `TestWeakPtrAlive`.  Or have I missed the point?

Comment: @G.M. Yes. `t` waits 1 second, that should be long enough for the main thread to free an `int` pointer.

Comment: The reason that the shared pointer is copied is that that's how thread creation works: the new thread gets a copy of the arguments. It doesn't look at the types that the thread function expects. If you want to pass by reference, you need to call the thread constructor with `std::ref(p)`. If you want to pass a `weak_ptr`, you have to create it by passing `std::weak_ptr(p)`.

Comment: Re: "that should be long enough" -- you can't write thread-safe code by guessing about what might be the case. Your instincts will almost always be wrong. There is no synchronization around `p = nullptr;`, so the behavior of the program is undefined. And the worst part of it is that the code will work "just fine" when you're testing it, and it will fail when you're demonstrating it for your most important client.

Comment: @PeteBecker This is a toy example, my real program has proper synchronization. And the thread creation does look at the types of the arguments: the compilation fails if `p` is replaced by `7` in the construction of `t`.

Comment: @V.Semeria -- slow down. You don't know as much about this as you think you do. The `std::thread` constructor simply **copies** its arguments; it does not decide what type it expects by looking at the thread function. Inside the code that sets up the new thread, the thread function gets called **with the copies** of the arguments that were passed to the thread constructor. So, yes, if the types aren't convertible, it's an error. Not because the arguments can't be passed to the constructor; they can and they are; but hecause **inside the constructor** the objects can't be converted.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ok so what I observe complies with the specification of thread creation. I will add the weak_ptr manually in my code. Do you know why it was specified so ? It would be more convenient for programmers that type conversions be done before the constructor call, so that the compiler checks that the arguments have exactly the same types as in the thread function.

Comment: One big danger area is taking an argument by reference. In a single thread, the value of that argument won't change while the function is running unless the called function changes it. In a thread function, after the constructor returns, the creating thread can modify the value, so that property would disappear. Copying the value ensures that there aren't any such surprises lurking under the surface. Sharing an object between threads requires doing something extra, like `std::ref(p)` to, in effect, pass by reference.

Comment: The constructor of `std::thread` cannot analyze the signature of the thread function. Either it is callable with the arguments that the constructor receives and stores (OK), or it is not (compilation error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those implementations copy the `shared_ptr`. i.e. They copy the argument and tie it to the lifetime of the thread. Copying is the default for argument binding with thread creation.

This wouldn't be considered a bug unless the standard said the implementation couldn't do that.

As far as getting the behavior you want, I think you'd have the same problem if you used a lambda. Instead you could use a functor, or you could use some global or static variables.

Here's your example converted to use a functor. The benefit is that you control the member variables. The downside is the boilerplate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

class TestWeakPtrAlive
{
    std::weak_ptr<int> m_pw;

public:
    TestWeakPtrAlive(std::weak_ptr<int> pw)
        : m_pw(std::move(pw))
    {}
  
    void operator()()
    {
        // wait for main thread to delete pw
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        std::shared_ptr<int> p = m_pw.lock();
        std::cout << (p ? "pw alive" : "pw dead")
                  << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> p = std::make_shared<int>(18);
    auto functor = TestWeakPtrAlive(p);
    std::thread t(std::move(functor));
    p = nullptr;
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** I just thought of a fairly obvious solution which would be to just create a weak_ptr and pass that to the thread constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void TestWeakPtrAlive(std::weak_ptr<int> pw)
{
    // wait for main thread to delete pw
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    std::shared_ptr<int> p = pw.lock();
    std::cout << (p ? "pw alive" : "pw dead")
        << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> p = std::make_shared<int>(18);
    std::weak_ptr<int> wp = p;
    std::thread t(TestWeakPtrAlive, std::move(wp));
    p = nullptr;
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```